# Event Viewer snapin fails after a power outage

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer, mmc

I was in the middle of opening a saved event log from another computer when our building was hit with a power outage, and my desktop is not protected.

After recovering from the power outage, I get an error box with the message "MMC has detected an error in a snap-in and will unload it". After dismissing the box with the "Unload snap-in and continue runnning" option checked, I get an "Unhandled exeption in managed code" message box calling out an Argument Exception with the message "The following string cannot be null or empty: Display Name".

Things I've tried:
1) SFC /SCANNOW - scan was clean
2) Deleting the AppData/Local/Microsoft/EventViewer/Settings.xml file
3) An ad hoc search of the registry for any settings related to "eventvwr" that might have gotten corrupted - didn't find any

Event Viewer appears to work okay except for any attempt to access any saved files. Even clicking the "Saved Logs" node in the action pane on the left causes the error.

This is on 64-bit Windows 7 SP1, running on a quad-core i7-2600 w/ 16 Gig of RAM.

Any ideas?  I am definitely resistant to the idea of re-installing windows.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: is it only the event viewer snapin with an issue?